# in asp.net 4.5 with fileupload how can Check zip for file extensions

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, webforms, zip

Hi i have the standard file upload control in asp.net 4.5, and i limit what users can upload by checking the file extension. All works a treat but i know need to allow them to upload a zip file.

**My Problem**

Now i only want to allow the zip file if the files inside are of the extenions i allow {pdf, txt, doc . etc}.

I have tried the below:

```
 Using archive As IO.Compression.ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(File.InputStream.ToString)


 End Using
```

The above wont work becuase ZipFile.OpenRead(Needs the path of the zip folder). So how can i acces the file without having to save it to disk. Do have I have to save it to disc in a temp folder first?

Ideally as .NET 4.5 has compression i dont want to use third party tools.

Thanks

Comment: when a user send a file it will be temporary in a temp folder, so actually you can access it

Comment: thanks. How? I cant seem to get it

Comment: that just returns to me the HttpPostedFile. But from there how can i access it to use ZipFile.OpenRead(file path) ??

System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(File.FileName) just returns "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\nameofzip.zip" which then says file not found.

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to read the archive file all thats needed is as below:

```
Using archive As New IO.Compression.ZipArchive(HttpPostedFile.InputStream)

end using
```

*notice the new zipArchive here takes the HttpPostedFile.inputStream. The code snippet i was using above in my question was taken from the micorosft site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx. Which was not working.

Thankyou @user2675751 for your comments